# Change left right padding of TableviewCell in iOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, padding, collectionview

I'm trying to make a bubble `UITableviewCell`. the cell has a `UILabel` with all `edges` pin to edges of cell `ContentView` and `UITableView` is using `AutomaticHeight` (base on `Label.text`) I have set the `CellBackgroundView` image as the function below

```
func changeImage(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: name) else { return nil }
        return image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 30, bottom: 17, right: 30), resizingMode: .stretch).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
```

Above function is called in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: changeImage("right_bubble"))
```

I have a background image look like a bubbles:

[image]

The problem is I cannot change the left or right `padding` of the `Cell`. Is there a way to change the padding (might be left or right) (to distinguish between sender and receiver) or need to change from `UITableView` to `UICollectionView`?

### Edit

I have come out with a solution to change constraint dynamically in Custom Cell subclass. Bellow is the implementation of the subclass

```
import UIKit

enum Direction {
    case left
    case right
}

class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var messageText: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func configureCell(with message: Message, direction: Direction ) {
        self.messageText?.text = message.text
        
        switch direction {
        case .left:
            backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
            self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage.changeImage("left_bubble")
            self.backgroundImageView.tintColor = .lightGray
        case .right:
            backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
            self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage.changeImage("right_bubble")
            self.backgroundImageView.tintColor = .blue
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

but running to an issue with `Autolayout` when number rows exceeds screen height and require scrolling. Below is the error:

```
2018-11-03 19:53:36.478275+0800 VicGithubDM[2352:34611] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006e9090 V:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x7fe37dd3bb70'still have some bugs stil...']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe37dd3b750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006ea620 V:[UILabel:0x7fe37dd3bb70'still have some bugs stil...']-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe37dd3b750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006e1d10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe37dd3b750.height == 1.19209e-07   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006ea620 V:[UILabel:0x7fe37dd3bb70'still have some bugs stil...']-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe37dd3b750 )>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making a custom cell and changing values of constraints ​​depending on the type.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented a solution of constraint but running to an issue with auto layout. Can help me see the update question?